# Item in listView are not clickable using keyboard enter key

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to navigate in listView using keyboard. Normally enter button works on other control. But it is not working when I select and Item (using keyboard) and press the enter key.

I am using setOnKeyListener inside getView.
This is code of my Adapter class.
CustomUsersAdapter class which extends ArrayAdapter class.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
        }
        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                this.onClicked("onKeyListener");
                return true;
            }
        });

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                this.onClicked("setOnClickListener");
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Neither onClick in OnClickListener or OnKeyListener are called.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting onClickListener to its root view in the adapter. You should try to set these listeners to your listview object. Such as;

```
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes that works. But any insight  why the setOnClickListener set on the view returned by adapter is not working?
But same thing works when I use touchevent instead of keyboard's enter.

Comment: not sure but it could be related to root view of a listView item. how do you navigate your listview using keyboard? Is the listview focusable and clickable?

Comment: What do you min by root view of a listView item here? Do you mean the root   of View returned by Adapter? I am using simple listView for  list items , here is a sample. Also I tried using setting list item view as focusable and clickable before returning from getView of Adapter

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format here
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName1"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:text="User first"/>
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName2"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="User last"/>
</LinearLayout>